# Fetch a value from sql with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i use asp.net web page and when i want fetch value a -field from database that is sqlserver 2012 it fetch ID_SERVICE of first row in TABLE and not fetch ID_SERVICE That i want
here is my code :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                            .ConnectionStrings["SeylanehSabzConnectionString"]
                            .ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select ID_SERVICE From HR.Service Where ID_PERSONEL=" + 
       DropDownListVisitor.DataValueField;
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
serviceid = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: What are you saying there? What is the question?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please clarify it. What is the value of `DropDownListVisitor.DataValueField` exactly ?

Comment: You should probably include information about what is going on. Why is it not working, what is your intended output and what are you getting instead, etc.

Comment: serviceid should get ID_SERVICE where ID_PERSONEL=@ID_PERSONEL but serviceid get ID_SERVICE first value of table my table is : ID SERVICE - ID_PERSONEL - ... AND ID_PERSONEL GET Value From DropDownListVisitor

Comment: @behzad Then look at [`Tim's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19807354/447156). I think you mixing between `DataValueField` and `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the most important: [use sql-parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28SQL.105%29.aspx) instead of concatenating strings to build your sql-query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select ID_SERVICE From HR.Service Where ID_PERSONEL=@ID_PERSONEL";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_PERSONEL", int.Parse(DropDownListVisitor.SelectedValue));
```

Second, i assume you want to use the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx). The [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just gets/sets the name of the column you want to use for the `DropDownList`'s value.

Comment: I totally agree. Looks like the main problem OP doesn't know what `DataValueField` and `SelectedValue` is for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

at the end of your query.

Comment: But why OP should do that? I don't see any reason.

Answer (score 0):

> use a DataAdapter instead,  to store the results fetched from DB and then from DataAdapter extract your need.

Comment: Why? I think OP wants to get first row of first result that's why `ExecuteScalar` is totally fits here.

Comment: what is first row of first result ? i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select ID_SERVICE From HR.Service Where ID_PERSONEL=" + 
       DropDownListVisitor.DataValueField;
```

The property DataValueField contains a field name, not the currently selected item or its value. Use SelectedValue instead - and of course use parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks.